# c# Application.Current.Windows does not include all windows

Tags: c#

In an application, I need to open multiple popups but need to check if a popup already exists with a given reference (guid). If so, I will first close the existing popup and open a new one. I am using the below code but it looks like if my partial class variable Guid is reset each time a new popup is created and therefore the condition MRwin.GetGuid() == this.guid is always true. It is like if the guid variable was declared as static :-S
Any idea?

```
public partial class MyPopup: MetroWindow 
{
  private Guid guid;

  public Guid GetGuid() 
  {
    return guid;
  }

  public MyPopup(Guid guid) 
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.guid = guid;

    foreach(var win in Application.Current.Windows) 
    {
      if (win is Forms.MyPopup) 
      {
        Forms.MyPopup cWin = (Forms.MyPopup) win;

        // Close if there is any open popup window related to the same Guid
        if (cWin.GetGuid() == this.guid) 
        {
          cWin.Close();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The code you've provided won't compile - you're trying to assign a `string` value to a `Guid` variable. For the sake of readability, I'd also recommend that you format your code - at least on Stack Overflow - in a more conventional C# way. (I'd also suggest using a property instead of a `GetGuid` method...)

Comment: Note that we don't know what's providing the constructor parameter, either. If the same value is being passed in every time, then sure, all the windows will be the same... Please provide a [mcve] so we can help you.

Comment: Typo? You assign the Guid type field with a string value, in the constructor

Comment: How are you assigning guids to those popups? Are you certain they are different?

Comment: Hi Hans, Jon, thanks for your fast feedback. Sorry fo the typo made in simplifying the code, it is updated. Yes, the values are different: When I create the new popup, I do a print of the Guid which are different every time. Then, when the guide are accessed through the loop through the form, it seems that they got erased and I can't figure out why/when.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, Application.Current.Windows did not include one of the opened windows certainly due to threading.
To address the issue I decided create and maintain a list of opened windows using a static list.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bad job for the constructor. If you don't need to create a window, don't create it. Creating it and then closing it isn't reasonable. And it causes your issue, since your newly *partially* created window is already in the `Application.Current.Windows` list!

Instead of having this kind of logic in a constructor, use a static method (or a factory):

```
public static MyPopup OpenPopup(Guid guid) =>
  Application.Current.Windows
    .OfType<Forms.MyPopup>()
    .FirstOrDefault(w => w.GetGuid() == guid)
  ?? new MyPopup(guid);
```

(feel free to return `null` if you don't want to return a reference to an existing popup).

Comment: Thanks. The need is slightly different in fact. Based on a trigger, I need to either update/refresh multiple popup values or (the option that I chose), close the specific popup and open a fresh one with the refreshed values. Anyway, I tried your approach but it seems that the Application.Current.Windows is not set when using static method.

Comment: Ok, so I identified the issue: the Application.Current.Windows sometimes misses to return one of the active form. It looks to be the one opened first but I am not sure why... I have one single call to the constructor in the the main thread.
+1 for the helpful "newly partially created window is already in the Application.Current.Windows list!"

Comment: @Salim Are you creating all the windows on the UI thread? Dealing with multi-threaded UI is very tricky. `Application.Current.Windows` keeps track of all the windows created on the *current* thread.

Comment: Hi Luaan, well, I have a few threads but I am creating all the windows from the main one. I am not sure why the first one did not get registered :-/ Anyway. I will edit the post to make sure it reflects the outcome of the analysis.
Thanks!

Comment: @Salim Application is thread-safe. Are you sure you're not doing something weird in the constructors (or static constructors)? Are all the windows WPF windows? Also note that the first window you create becomes the `Application.Current.MainWindow`, so the first one is always a bit special.

Comment: Hi @Luaan, thanks. The application is an Outlook Add-In where I have a WPF popup that I call a couple of time. To my understanding, even the first instantiation should be present in the Application.Current.Windows. Right?

Comment: @Salim I have no idea what's the threading/domain model of Outlook Add-Ins, sorry :) That's definitely a special case that can have unexpected impact on what you're trying to do.